# Combine factor/cluster levels into clusters of certain size in R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, cluster-analysis

I have a simple dataframe reproducible by running:

```
structure(list(cluster = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 
4L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
1L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 11L, 4L, 
4L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 13L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 
3L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 
2L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 11L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 
3L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 6L), clusterSize = c(8L, 9L, 6L, 19L, 19L, 6L, 13L, 19L, 
19L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 19L, 12L, 19L, 6L, 9L, 19L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 
13L, 13L, 19L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 
19L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 13L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 19L, 11L, 
9L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 19L, 11L, 13L, 19L, 
13L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 
13L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 13L, 
19L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 19L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 
13L, 3L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 19L, 13L)), .Names = c("cluster", 
"clusterSize"), row.names = c(NA, -129L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
head(clusterdata)

   cluster clusterSize
1       1           8
2       2           9
3       3           6
4       4          19
5       4          19
6       5           6
```

I have a total of 15 clusters and a total of 129 observations . I need to have each cluster size be 9. It's okay if there are not 15 clusters in the end.

In other words, I would like to combine clusters in a way that produces clusters of size no more than 9 and possibly leave a cluster that is smaller than 9. Clusters that are originally bigger than 9 should be split up but always keep 9 as the size and put the remaining in a "left-over" cluster/s. Cluster that are originally smaller than 9 should combine with other clusters to form clusters of size 9 while putting the remaining in the "left-over" cluster/s.

I have no idea how to go about this in R.  Any ideas would be much appreciated...

Comment: If it were clustering, it would be based on multiple attributes, distances, etc. - I don't think this is a clustering problem, but rather the classic knapsack problem.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, The cluster assignments have already taken place, so this is not an explicit clustering problem but rather a subset of such.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The knapsack problem/solution seems interesting in this application.  Any ideas on the implementation in such?